# Video Rendering Issues in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, html5-video

So I was rendering a video in my react website using the below code :

```
<video src='/assets/video/2.mp4' autoPlay={true} loop={true}/>
```

Although this was working fine.But when I refresh my chrome browser the video is not playing.
I searched for a solution but was unable to resolve it.

But when I changed my code to :

```
<video src='/assets/video/2.mp4' autoPlay={true} loop={true} muted={true}/>
```

My video plays even on browser refresh.

I can't find the reason for this.
I am still a newbie in react and any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not a React issue but more of a web policy in which browsers would prevent videos from autoplaying unmuted.

[Google's Explanation](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes)

A workaround that I could think of:

User interactions with your website could bypass this autoplay restriction. You could start the video muted but unmute it if the user interacts with the page?

Look for some React video player libraries to help you with that unmuting / muting controls. E.g.:

- [Video.js](https://docs.videojs.com/tutorial-react.html)

Hope this helps to clarify!